# Background color split into stripes in listings package

Tags: color, listings, unicode

How can we remove the white spaces in background?

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Khmer OS}
\setsansfont{Khmer OS}
\setmonofont{Khmer OS}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{%
    language=[LaTeX]TeX,
    basicstyle=\ttfamily,
    backgroundcolor=\color{magenta!5}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Khmer OS}
\begin{document}
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item តើមានអ្វីកើតឡើង?
    \item សូមមើលផ្ទៃខាងក្រោយនៃកូដនេះ
  \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The chars are "too high" for the line that is highlighted by listings. You may want to try a different approach (maybe tcolorbox and its tcblisting).

Comment: you can change fontsize for listings via `\lstset` globally or by adding options locally to the listing.

Comment: @naphaneal Does it really work by changing the font size?

Comment: Any news here? Did you find a solution?